# Yes/no answer to "Have you closed all of your tickets?" if there were no tickets to begin with

Tags: questions

My boss asked the question, "Have you closed all of your tickets?" to me and my co-workers.  One of my co-workers, who did not have any tickets to begin with, answered yes.  We are conflicted as to weather yes is the correct answer to this question, vs. "Are all of your tickets closed?" or, "Do you have any open tickets?"

Comment: What's wrong with the statement you used in your title? _There were no tickets to begin with._

Comment: We were wondering if there was a correct yes/no answer to the question.  I will edit to reflect that

Comment: Sounds like it should be a question for your boss, "how should we answer that question if we have no tickets to begin with?" :-)

Comment: There isn't a correct yes/no answer. Consider the question "Have you stopped beating your wife?" No yes/no answer will be suitable because both questions are (I hope) based on incorrect premises, namely that _you had open tickets_ and _you are a wife beater_.

Comment: @Kristina Lopez, we asked him and he was also unsure.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins, you raise a valid point.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: The correct answer is [MU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative))

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a question of logic not language *per se*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all questions can have a yes or no answer, and the way the question is phrased (and the presupposiitons it makes) often determines if an answer applies, and what it is.

The classic example of this is ["have you stopped beating your wife"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45202/whats-the-term-when-you-ask-a-question-which-implies-a-lie/51327#51327)

The REAL correct answer to the question is not yes or no, but to clear up the presupposition that there were open tickets to begin with.

However if you want to be pedantic you can logically get to either "yes" OR "no":

> Every ticket assigned to me (0 of them) is now closed, so yes.

or

> I have closed NO tickets today, so no.

Comment: "Every ticket assigned to me (0 of them) is now closed, so yes." is false since no tickets were closed; unless someone who has no car can answer "yes" to "did you clean your car today?" , since all his cars (all 0 of them) are clean. "stopped beating" is different (and not always answerable with yes-no) since there are 2 actions (stopping and beating)

Comment: I left no ticket open, and no car uncleaned!

Comment: nonetheless, answering with "yes" to "did your clean your car?", when you do not have one, would be a lie.

Comment: @msam ... just as answering "no" would be a lie.

Comment: we might have a different understanding of "lie"

Comment: So if I followed up with "it's ok that you didn't clean it, just come pick me up in your dirty car," you didn't just lie about having an unclean car?  I feel like you're just being obtuse since you know my answer is above (no answer, clear up presupposition).

Comment: "i don't have a car, and never said that I did". But I'll stop here since this is turning into a discussion about logic

Answer (score 0):

"Have you closed all of your tickets?" is a yes-no question. One possible logical argument is that the main action of the question is the closing of tickets. Since no tickets were closed the correct answer would be "no".

However, the inferred meaning of such a question must be taken into consideration. Assuming the manager was more interested in knowing about outstanding work, the inferred question would be "Did you finish your work?". In this case, "yes" is also a correct answer.

An even better unambiguous answer, would have been "I didn't have any".